# var-create unable to create variable object

Tags: c++, debugging, clion

When I debug c++ (in clion), I can't watch **global strings**. I tried to check other types but it worked well.

Also, I tried **local** string and I can watch it too?!

[image: this is a screenshot of the program]

Comment: Don't post links to images of text. Copy-paste the actual text, as text, into the question body instead. Please  [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As for your problem, what version of Clion are you using? I remember there being some problems with `std::string` in the debugger view in early versions, but that's been fixed for quite some time now.

Comment: non const `char*` to string literals are deprecated ( to stop you trying to modify the string literal ), try `const char* f ="RBYG";`

Comment: Lastly, you definitely need to read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: i use version: 2016.3.2 i think it is the latest one.

Comment: i can watch char*f the problem is with y i can;t watch it

Comment: I can replicate it. It must be a bug, and as such I recommend you go to [the Clion bug-tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP), search for it (to see if it have already been reported), and if not then add it. If it has been reported then +1 the existing issue.

Comment: Also please forgive the first part of my first comment, because the text (the code) is not really relevant in this case. The image is fine in this case. Though remember it for future questions. :)

Comment: no problem i will report for the bug and thanks for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just in case, the issue is now tracked as [CPP-8693](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-8693).

The root cause is somehow related to libstdc++ [dual ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc%2B%2B/manual/using_dual_abi.html). 
Global symbols of `std::string` types are mangled differently, which in turn confuses GDB.

> In the GCC 5.1 release libstdc++ introduced a new library ABI that includes new implementations of `std::string` and `std::list`. These changes were necessary to conform to the 2011 C++ standard which forbids Copy-On-Write strings and requires lists to keep track of their size.

Given the following code:

```
std::string global_var = "Hi there!";
static std::string static_var = "Hello";
```

Here's the related `nm` output:

```
0000000000602240 B _Z10global_varB5cxx11
0000000000602280 b _ZL10static_var
```

A possible **workaround** is to disable C++11 ABI. In CMakeLists.txt, add the following line, right after the `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` line, if any:

```
add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)
```

This makes symbol names to be mangled differently, in a way GDB is happy again:

```
0000000000602238 B global_var
0000000000602248 b _ZL10static_var
```

Comment: Hey Eldar! Thanks for the answer. Is there any other way I could get around the same problem without using -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0. As I use one of the libraries compiled using -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1, my compiled program crashes before the start giving segmentation fault. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @krishnachaitanya not that I am aware of, unfortunately.

Comment: this advice doen't help, because i get link errors with opencv using this flag