# Why this function has segmentation fault?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define E 1E-3

long double Fun(long double x);

int main() {
    long double a = 0;
    long double b = 1;
    long double temp;
    while(fabsl(a - b) > E){
        temp = a + b;
        temp = temp / 2;
        long double Funa = Fun(a);
        long double Funb = Fun(b);
        long double Funtemp = Fun(temp);

        if(Funtemp == 0){
            printf("temp = %Lf\n",temp);
            break;
        }

        if(Funtemp * Funa < 0){
            a = temp;
        }

        else if(Funtemp * Funb < 0) {
            b = temp;
        }
    }
    printf("a = %Lf\nb = %Lf", a, b);

    return 0;
}

long double Fun(long double x){
    return x*x*x + x*x - 1;
}
```

I don't know why the Fun() has segmentation fault? Really confused.

here are the information reported by clion below:

```
clion: 
Fun(a) = -var-create: unable to create variable object
Signal = SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)
```

Comment: It's at the bottom.

Comment: Identifying your platform would probably be helpful; this doesn't fault for me (thought it does seem to hang) on 64-bit intel / Linux.

Comment: Can't reproduce.    The code has an infinite loop though.

Comment: @user3629249: It isn't recursive really, the `E` in `1E-3` isn't its own token.

Comment: @user3629249: In Standard C, there is no such thing as a recursive macro.

Comment: In particular, it'd be helpful to know the compiler / version you are using.

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling this a C and not C++? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41854840/var-create-unable-to-create-variable-object

Comment: Upon further reading, this is often caused by a mismatch between the compiler version and the debugger version.

Answer (score 1):

Your segmentation fault could be caused by using `long double` on hardware that doesn't support it. Just try the same with `double` instead. On many platforms, including MSVC, `double` and `long double` use the same number of bits.

Another segmentation fault cause could be incompatible libraries working with `long double`, see for example [this report](https://github.com/mingwpy/mingwpy/issues/22) in gcc on mingw. That would be the case if your segmentation fault happens when you try to execute `fabsl`.

Anyway, following code seems to not be doing what you expect:

```
    if(Funtemp * Funa < 0){
        a = temp;
    }
    else if(Funtemp * Funb < 0) {
        b = temp;
    }
```

This easily produces an endless loop.

You typically want `Funa` and `Funb` to always have opposite sign. So if `Funa` and `Funtemp` have opposite sign, you want to assign temp to `b`. And vice versa. Maybe also add a test in case all 3 have the same sign:

```
    if(Funtemp * Funa < 0){
        b = temp;
    }
    else if(Funtemp * Funb < 0) {
        a = temp;
    }
    else {
        printf("no solution possible\n");
        break;
    }
```

And, instead of stopping when the difference between `a` and `b` gets 1E-3, you could continue until temp gets equal to `a` or to `b`. `a` and `b` are moving very quickly towards each other, only getting into trouble when the `(a+b)/2` step gets rounded to either `a` or `b`.

```
while(true){
    temp = a + b;
    temp = temp / 2;
    if (temp == a || temp == b)
        break;
    ...
```